# VBA Range_Copy Macro - How to apply same task to subsequent rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working spreadsheet with lists of items.  One field could have 1 of 14 descriptions.  I thought creating a macro would be quicker than manually going to a separate sheet and copying and pasting the desired description every time.

I am totally new to this, but was able to create a macro grabbing data in cell A1 in one sheet and adding that data to cell S3 in another sheet - see code below. (Each description has its own sheet with data in cell A1)  My question is, how to move onto the next row and cell S4.  Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Range_Copy()

Worksheets("Used Single Items Returns").Range("A1").Copy Worksheets("Gopher Items CSV Test").Range("S3")

End Sub
```

Comment: "One field could have 1 of 14 descriptions" - what determines which of the 14 you copy and paste?

Comment: A little more details - The spreadsheet contains listing information for items we are selling on eBay.  When completed, it will be imported into an eBay listing software.  The descriptions vary based on  a few different factors like, quantity, item condition, shipping methods, return policies.  There are 14 different types.  The person adding the item details will determine which description to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to copy into Col S on the selected row:

```
Sub Range_Copy()
    Dim r
    Set r = Selection.Cells(1).entirerow.range("S1") 'relative to row, not sheet
    Worksheets("Used Single Items Returns").Range("A1").Copy r
End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you so much, Tim.  This will work great for us.